# How do I root my LG G4 Beat phone?

Tags: rooting, lg

I am fine with staying with the current Android OS but I just want root in order to be able to change the default installation location, etc.

I also want to know how I will be able to unroot it.

I do not wish to use Kingroot at all.
I am asking this because I couldn't find any guide about rooting LG G4 Beat.
I want a safe and reliable way that won't need too many permissions and won't upload my private data to remote servers like KingRoot does, I read in the internet that that's what it does and that is pretty creepy so I would like to avoid using KingRoot or any other one click root app, I can follow steps as long as they are clear and not too complicated

Answer (score 0):

find a custom recovery for your device like TWRP or CWM then flash it or boot it in temp mode using commands like
fastboot flash recovery twrp.img or fastboot boot recovery cwm.img

then download su.zip from chainfire website and flash that zip vola your device is rooted

you might have to oem unlock bootloader to do this

for that use command

fastboot oem unlock

Answer (score 0):

try this guide to root your phone safely http://rootmygalaxy.net/root-lg-g4-beat-g4sh735/

Hope this helps